# Tab and Shift-Tab smart indent on selected text

Tags: haskell, emacs

It's standard in most modern editors that you can highlight a piece of code and indent or unindent a tab or however many spaces you're using; how do you do this in emacs?

So, for example I just opened sublime text, highlighted the following piece of code:

```haskell
variation1 person phoneMap carrierMap addressMap =
    case M.lookup person phoneMap of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just number ->
          case M.lookup number carrierMap of
            Nothing -> Nothing
            Just carrier -> M.lookup carrier addressMap
```

then pressed tab and got

```haskell
  variation1 person phoneMap carrierMap addressMap =
      case M.lookup person phoneMap of
        Nothing -> Nothing
        Just number ->
            case M.lookup number carrierMap of
              Nothing -> Nothing
              Just carrier -> M.lookup carrier addressMap
```

one shift-tab on that code returns it back to where it was, and if I continuing pressing shift-tab I eventually get the following:

```haskell
variation1 person phoneMap carrierMap addressMap =
case M.lookup person phoneMap of
Nothing -> Nothing
Just number ->
case M.lookup number carrierMap of
Nothing -> Nothing
Just carrier -> M.lookup carrier addressMap
```

Quote from another response:

> emacs language modes don't really have a notion of 'indent this block
>   1 tab further'. Instead they're very opinionated and have a notion of
>   'this is the correct indentation' and that's what you get when you hit
>   tab in a language mode.

Except when I do that with the following code (haskell mode and ghc mod enabled):

```haskell
import Monad
import System
import IO
import Random
import Control.Monad.State

type RandomState a = State StdGen a
data CountedRandom = CountedRandom {
      crGen :: StdGen
    , crCount :: Int
    }

type CRState = State CountedRandom

getRandom :: Random a => RandomState a
getRandom =
  get >>= \gen ->
  let (val, gen') = random gen in
  put gen' >>
  return val
```

I get the following:

```haskell
import Monad
  import System
  import IO
  import Random
  import Control.Monad.State

type RandomState a = State StdGen a
data CountedRandom = CountedRandom {
  crGen :: StdGen
  , crCount :: Int
  }

type CRState = State CountedRandom

               getRandom :: Random a => RandomState a
               getRandom =
  get >>= \gen ->
  let (val, gen') = random gen in
  put gen' >>
  return val
```

when I wanted

```haskell
import Monad
import System
import IO
import Random
import Control.Monad.State

type RandomState a = State StdGen a
data CountedRandom = CountedRandom {
      crGen :: StdGen
    , crCount :: Int
    }

type CRState = State CountedRandom

getRandom :: Random a => RandomState a
getRandom =
  get >>= \gen ->
    let (val, gen') = random gen in
    put gen' >>
    return val
```

---

Near enough to a solution from ataylor:

```lisp
(defcustom tab-shift-width 4
  "Sets selected text shift width on tab"
  :type 'integer)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'tab-shift-width)

(global-set-key 
 (kbd "<tab>")
 (lambda (start end)
   (interactive "r")
   (if (use-region-p)
       (save-excursion
     (let ((deactivate-mark nil))
       (indent-rigidly start end tab-shift-width)))
     (indent-for-tab-command))))

(global-set-key 
 (kbd "S-<tab>")
 (lambda (start end)
   (interactive "r")
   (if (use-region-p)
       (save-excursion
     (let ((deactivate-mark nil))
       (indent-rigidly start end (- tab-shift-width))))
     (indent-for-tab-command))))
```

It'd be nice if emacs had support for indent detection (i.e., just grab the value of some variable); the closest thing I found to this was a plugin called dtrt indent but it doesn't work for Haskell.

Comment: Dunno about emacs, but in vim there's a rectangular-selection mode; inserting text in rectangular selection mode inserts that text in the same place on every line. Such a thing should solve your problem, if emacs has an analog (and it probably does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indent-region` will reindent a block of text according to the current mode.

To force an indentation level to be added, you can use `string-rectangle`, which will prompt you for a string.  Here you can provide the string for an indentation level (e.g. a tab, 4 spaces, etc.).  The string will be inserted on each line of the currently selected region, in the current column, effectively indenting it.  Alternatively, you can get a similar effect from `open-rectangle`, which will insert whitespace into the rectangle with corners defined by the point and the mark.

Another way to force indentation is to call `indent-rigidly` (<kbd>C-x TAB</kbd>).  This overrides the mode specific indentation rules and indents a fixed amount.  The numeric argument specifies how much to indent, and a negative argument will unindent.  If you want this to be the default behavior when a region is selected, you could do something like this:

```
(global-set-key 
 (kbd "<tab>")
 (lambda (start end)
   (interactive "r")
   (if (use-region-p)
       (save-excursion
     (let ((deactivate-mark nil))
       (indent-rigidly start end 4)))
     (indent-for-tab-command))))
```

Comment: How do I bind that to shift-tab/tab so that it reads what kind of indentation I'm using and applies the desired behavior? Do I have to learn elisp to add the standard behavior given in most other editors?

Comment: Updated my answer.  `indent-rigidly` does approximately what you want.  Added an example of how you could bind it to `TAB` when a region is selected.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell code is incredibly difficult to indent correctly, because there are multiple "correct" indentations for a piece of code.

`haskell-mode` has a very specific line format that it expects you to follow (As in, you have to make line breaks in the right places) and it has a few indentation rules for formatting code that matches that line format. These rules exist to make the automatic indentation results more consistent. The rules are roughly this:

- After every keyword that introduces a block, you should make a line break or make sure that the entire block fits into the layout. Otherwise, you get a lot of hanging blocks like in your `getRandom` example
- All blocks are indented exactly two spaces. This includes module blocks; if you do `module Bla where`, the whole part after that line will be indented. This means that you should keep the default Haskell module file format for the indentation order to work out.
- The indentation of a line needs to be as unambiguous as possible; if a line could mean different things depending on its indentation, it will lead to it being indented to the position that `haskell-mode` thinks makes sense in the context. Fixing this can be impossible in some cases.

Because it is impossible to structure Haskell code so that it meets the requirements of `haskell-mode`, you cannot indent a while Haskell code file like this. You need to only use automatic indentation locally. This can be done in a number of ways:

- When you are on a line, you can indent the current line to the most likely "correct" position with regards to the previous line by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>. By pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> again, you will bring the line to the "next" indentation level, and continuously cycle through all possible logical indentation steps.
- If you select a series of blocks that are found locally (The body of a function etc.) and use <kbd>M-x indent-region</kbd>, the result will most likely be correct.

What I usually do in a situation like this is to start on the line that has the "wrong" indentation, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> once, and go down line-by-line, pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> one or multiple times on each line until the indentation of that line is correct. The current "logical indentation positions" for the current line are calculated from the preceding code context, so correcting the indentation from the top almost always yields the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I highlight the area and hit `C-M-\`. It is `indent-region` and more fun can be found at the [multi-line indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html) page.

Comment: When I do that (C-M-\\) on my code sample it just looks like the last example in my question (missing all tabs). And when I use indent-code-rigidly it just moves it forward one space. Really, I want to find a bind or maybe an emacs plugin that gives me the tab/shift-tab behavior of every other code editor I've ever used. For example, in vim I would do `vmap <TAB> >gv
vmap <S-TAB> <gv`. How do I do the equivalent of *that* in emacs?

Comment: What language of code is that? from what i see in your code snippet is just moving 2 spaces, no?  So indent region will indent based 'where it should be' and takes the line above this snippet as it's baseline. Maybe this language has it's own indent-region in it's mode though?

Comment: It's haskell, and I cleared my .emacs when trying your suggestion. I just tried it with C++ code and it automatically indented the selection to what it thought it should be (it was wrong).

Comment: Ah, in my answer I was assuming you were using haskell-mode, go there to get it: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode

Comment: Yes, I tried it both ways. And in different languages: desired behavior not given.

Comment: I see what's happening now in your edit.  You're running into the fact that haskell-mode uses a bounce indenter.  A bounce indenter may give you a couple options and you hit tab multiple times to cycle through the indentation options.  When I put your code in emacs and select it all to indent I get what you do.  If I then go hit tab on the individual lines I can bounce to the correct indentation.  Not sure if there's a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

emacs language modes don't really have a notion of 'indent this block 1 tab further'. Instead they're very opinionated and have a notion of 'this is the correct indentation' and that's what you get when you hit tab in a language mode.

Once you get used to it anything else seems weird.  In your Haskell code those case statements only really have one indentation that's valid, anything else is a syntax error unless you add braces and semicolons.  If you really want to customize what emacs considers the 'right' indentation look at how to customize your mode.  A lot of language modes reuse the c-mode variables so [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html) is probably a good place to start (though I'm not sure what Haskell mode does, I've never found a need to customize it).

edit:
I see in your comment that your troubles are from not having Haskell mode installed, got to the [github page](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode) to get it.